I have no idea why the validation not work
I get the error message

DateMalformedStringException: Failed to parse time string (abc) at
position 0 (a): The timezone could not be found in the database

in my php unit test.
// ...
FAILED  Tests\Feature\Profile\UpdateTest > birthday is not date              
  Session is missing expected key [errors].
Failed asserting that false is true.

The following exception occurred during the last request:

DateMalformedStringException: Failed to parse time string (abc) at position 0 (a): The timezone could not be found in the database in /home/runner/work/New-Official-Website/New-Official-Website/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:100
Stack trace:
// ...
Cannot create dynamic property DateMalformedStringException::$xdebug_message
// ...

this is the validation, the required amd before_or_equal also has testing and passed
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Profile;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    //...
    public function rules(): array
    {
        // ...
        'birthday' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:'.now()->subYears(2)->format('Y-m-d'),
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

test:
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Profile;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UpdateTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    private $happyCase = [
        'username' => 'testing123',
        'family_name' => 'Chan',
        'given_name' => 'Diamond',
        'passport_type_id' => 2,
        'passport_number' => 'A1234567',
        'gender' => 'Male',
        'birthday' => '1997-07-01',
    ];
    // ...
    public function test_birthday_is_not_date()
    {
        $data = $this->happyCase;
        $data['birthday'] = 'abc';
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->put(route('profile.update'), $data);
        $response->assertInvalid(['birthday' => 'The birthday field must be a valid date.']);
    }
    // ...
}

but on local is pass
Only laravel 10 upgrade to 11 PR has this error.
PR link
https://github.com/Mensa-Hong-Kong/New-Official-Website/pull/5

yes but too more code that the system will said please add more desc than I have no more desc is problem, anyway, I will try to copy the code to here

Well, as per [ask] you're supposed to provide a [mre] of the specific issue. That isn't  just a big  dump of all your code - it's only the specific code needed to be able to reproduce your issue...nothing more, and nothing less. You may need to do some careful work to understand what the minimal needed code is (a process which, in itself, may help to lead you towards a solution anyway!). And a better description of the problem is always welcome too - e.g. providing the sample data being used, and a description of the steps needed to reproduce it. Just a raw error mesage alone is insufficient.

Man, I had an answer and the question closed right as I was sending it. I can't type that whole thing in a comment.

@ADyson, I changed to code but I think many desc is no need, just for let checking pass. And than, this laravel 10 up to 11, if this have to full repo, may the problem is not come from code, is come from upgrade or framework or github workflow and framework conflict, anyone can base on specific code to find it?

@IGP I've voted to re-open now that the OP has updated the question. Patience... :-)

Check ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php. There should be a getDatetime function around line 35X. That function should have an empty catch block like this

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-with-date-validation?page=1&replyId=955081 mentions this, it has to do with xdebug, not the validation itself. Try disabling xdebug.

@aynber work, DateMalformedStringException and xdebug error also have no warning, all test passed, but I have no idea disable xdebug if this is good idea. Or I should report to laravel/framework to let they fix the xdebug error

You may want to report it, just in case, XDebug is only for development and isn't necessary, or you can enable/disable it when you need to.

@aynber github action default is enable xdebug, on loacl, I am disable, but need on github workflow set disable, I think is not user friendly, anyway, 3Q so mach

DateMalformedStringException is an exception thrown when trying to create an invalid DateTime.
This will throw it.
new DateTime('abc', null);

This exact code is called by Carbon\Carbon in its constructor at ./vendor/nestbot/carbon/src/Carbon/traits/Creator.php around line 100.
        try {
            parent::__construct($time ?? 'now', $timezone);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            throw new InvalidFormatException($exception->getMessage(), 0, $exception);
        }

In older versions of Carbon (2.33.0 and under), this exception was not caught and rethrown as Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException;.
However, even if you're using an older version of Carbon, Laravel should be catching the exception.
Are the vendor files modified in any way? Check the following files:

./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php.

Around line 335 you should see this method:
    protected function getDateTime($value)
    {
        try {
            return @Date::parse($value) ?: null;
        } catch (Exception) {
            // Here, the DateMalformedStringException or InvalidFormatExceptions are caught.
        }
    }

If they're not modified, have you extended them in any way that would alter this behavior?

I cannot change the vendor folder, error from github action workflow, the workflow will each time rebuild server and instaall comporser, so, each action vendor also is new. And than, you can see the UpdateRequest class is extend Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest, I have no change anythink or extended them in any way that would alter this behavior

And the FormRequest use the Validator behind the scenes. According to the stack trace, that's where your problem is. #6 /home/runner/work/New-Official-Website/New-Official-Website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php(284): Illuminate\Validation\Validator->getDateTime(). Perhaps something is wrong with the runner. I don't see odd things in the workflow files but I'm not sure why the runner has xdebug enabled.
